# CSS-Grid not working if its items are Angular components

Tags: angular, css, css-grid

I had a working code (in HTML/CSS grid) which consisted of a `css-grid` of 3 rows, 2 columns. The first row was navigation (spanning all columns), the middle was content (didn't span all columns) and the final was footer (spanning all the columns).

```
.body__div--background {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#33b1f8 37%,#6e90f6 100%); /*syntax linear-gradient(direction, color1 limit, color2 limit)*/
  color:#555555;
  font-family: Verdana;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
}

.css-grid-container{
  height:100vh; /*???*/
  display: grid;
  grid-gap:20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  /* 2columns*/
  grid-template-rows: auto 15fr 1fr; /* 3 rows. Auto takes height of navigation, remaining is divided into 2 rows, middle row (content) is 15 times larger than the 3rd row (footer).*/

}
```

The `css` to put the elements at proper places in the grid is

```
.css-grid-item__nav{
  grid-column: 1 / -1; //nav takes 1st row, all columns
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.css-grid-item__practice-div{
  grid-column: 1 / 2; //middle has two divs. This should go in row2, column1
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self:end;
}

.css-grid-item__create-div{
  grid-column: 2 / 3; //middle has two divs. This should go in row2, column2
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self:start;

}

.css-grid-item__footer{
  grid-column: 1 / -1; //footer goes in row 3, all columns
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
  background-color: white;
  color:black;

}
```

The HTML looked something like follows:

```
<body class="body__div--background"  >

  <div class="css-grid-container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light css-grid-item__nav"> 
     ... 
    </nav>

    <div class="css-grid-container__practice-div">  
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="css-grid-item__create-div">
    ...
    </div>

    <div class="css-grid-item__footer">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Later I decided to to use Angular. I created 3 Angular components, nav-component, content-component and footer-component. I copied the `css` and `html` to Angular's css/html files.

So, the nav-component's html file has the following content

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light css-grid-item__nav"> ... </nav>
```

and its css has the following content

```
.css-grid-item__nav{
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

The HTML of app component looks like the following:

```
<div class="body__div--background"  >

  <div class="css-grid-container">
    <app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
    <app-content-component></app-content-component>
    <app-footer-component></app-footer-component>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, the nav-component and footer-component occupies only 1 column instead of all the columns. The content-component's two divs are in column 2 instead of being in 1 column each of the grid.

How could I make my code work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code doesn't work in angular because

```
<app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
```

is the grid item tag now.
Either you change the layout or put css to app-nav-component

```
app-nav-component {
   grid-column: 1 / -1;
   grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I dont follow. The app-nav-component (<nav html...> ) already had class `css-grid-item__nav`. Its css is already `.css-grid-item__nav{
  grid-column: 1 / -1;  grid-row: 1 / 2;}`

Comment: Hi, Manu. If you inspect in browser you can see your html like i mentioned below:

 <div class="css-grid-container">
<app-nav-component>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light css-grid-item__nav"> 
     ... 
    </nav>
   </app-nav-component>
  </div>

So, now the grid container child element is <app-nav-component> custom html tag not the <nav> tag.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try in few minutes and would share my observation.

Comment: It didn't work, unfortunately. I further simplified the app. Now the container contains only `<app-nav-component>` (removed other components) but the nav component still doesn't span across the both the columns

Comment: apologies, I got it this time. I had added `app-nav-component ` in a wrong css file.It was suppose to be added in css file for html containing code `<div class="css-grid-container"> `

Comment: great to hear Manu.

Comment: Is it best practice to style the literal component or better to use the :host approach?

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to use the `:host` pseudo-class selector in the component's css file. So for:

```
<app-nav-component></app-nav-component>
```

I'd use something like the following in `nav.component.css` or `nav.component.scss`:

```
:host {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

This will do the same as what @nithalqb suggests, but it allows you to keep all of the css-styling specific to the component in one file. That makes it the preferred method for me, but use whichever method makes sense to you.